# Group and Sum multi-dimensional array after unwinding elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a multidimensional array below is my JSON data, I want the output mentioned below. Thanks for the help. I have tried two methods, 1. project with map there I am unable to group the data.
2. tried with unwind and group there unable to get the inside errorField array ("recordCount" : 73).

By using groupBy key needs to group by the results, if filed key matches & inside field--> detail key matches we need to merge those do document.

My JSON:

```
     [
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641"
      },
      "groupBy":{
         "$oid":"60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641"
      },
      "employer":{
         "$oid":"60d0e4001a6ccd764cb26df4"
      },
      "parameters":{
         "begin":"2020-01-01",
         "end":"2020-12-31"
      },
      "recordCount":74,
      "errorFields":[
         {
            "field":"employeeStatus",
            "recordCount":62,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10000986",
                     "10000990",
                     "10001020"
                  ],
                  "detail":"Active employees should not have term date. Termed employees should have term date.",
                  "recordCount":3
               },
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10001032"
                  ],
                  "detail":"Stale pay period data (no new check for over 30 days from queried end date)",
                  "recordCount":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "field":"ytdGrossWages.ytdTotalGrossWages",
            "recordCount":8,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10001211",
                     "10001269",
                     "10001328",
                     "10001395"
                  ],
                  "detail":"YTD total does not equal sum of YTD wage buckets",
                  "recordCount":4
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "timestamp":{
         "$date":"2021-07-19T18:35:59.031Z"
      },
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"60f5c615bc43cb00965ac647"
      },
      "groupBy":{
         "$oid":"60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641"
      },
      "employer":{
         "$oid":"60d0e4001a6ccd764cb26df4"
      },
      "parameters":{
         "begin":"2020-01-01",
         "end":"2020-12-31"
      },
      "recordCount":11,
      "errorFields":[
         {
            "field":"employeeStatus",
            "recordCount":11,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003644",
                     "10003680"
                  ],
                  "detail":"Active employees should not have term date. Termed employees should have term date.",
                  "recordCount":2
               },
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003667",
                     "10003694",
                     "10003807",
                     "10003789"
                  ],
                  "detail":"Stale pay period data (no new check for over 30 days from queried end date)",
                  "recordCount":4
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "field":"ssn",
            "recordCount":2,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003667"
                  ],
                  "detail":"The ssn field is required.",
                  "recordCount":1
               },
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003694"
                  ],
                  "detail":"The ssn must be 9 digits.",
                  "recordCount":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "field":"employeeHomeAddressCountry",
            "recordCount":1,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003694"
                  ],
                  "detail":"The employeeHomeAddressCountry field is required.",
                  "recordCount":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "timestamp":{
         "$date":"2021-07-19T18:36:05.135Z"
      },
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

I want output like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641"),
    "errorFields" : [
            {
                    "field" : "employeeStatus",
                    "recordCount" : 73,
                    "errorDetails" : [
                            {
                                    "recordIds" : [
                                            "10001032",
                                            "10003667",
                                            "10003694",
                                            "10003807",
                                            "10003789"
                                    ],
                                    "detail" : "Stale pay period data (no new check for over 30 days from queried end date)",
                                    "recordCount" : 5
                            },
                            {
                                    "recordIds" : [
                                            "10000986",
                                            "10000990",
                                            "10001020",
                                            "10001031",
                                            "10001035"
                                    ],
                                    "detail" : "Active employees should not have term date. Termed employees should have term date.",
                                    "recordCount" : 5
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "field" : "ytdGrossWages.ytdTotalGrossWages",
                    "recordCount" : 8,
                    "errorDetails" : [
                            {
                                    "recordIds" : [
                                            "10001211",
                                            "10001269",
                                            "10001328",
                                            "10001395"
                                    ],
                                    "detail" : "YTD total does not equal sum of YTD wage buckets",
                                    "recordCount" : 8
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "field" : "ssn",
                    "recordCount" : 2,
                    "errorDetails" : [
                            {
                                    "recordIds" : [
                                            "10003667"
                                    ],
                                    "detail" : "The ssn field is required.",
                                    "recordCount" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "recordIds" : [
                                            "10003694"
                                    ],
                                    "detail" : "The ssn must be 9 digits.",
                                    "recordCount" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
            "field":"employeeHomeAddressCountry",
            "recordCount":1,
            "errorDetails":[
               {
                  "recordIds":[
                     "10003694"
                  ],
                  "detail":"The employeeHomeAddressCountry field is required.",
                  "recordCount":1
               }
            ]
         }
    ]
```

}

Here is the mycode method 1:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { groupBy: ObjectId("60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641") } },
  { "$project": { 
    "_id": "$groupBy",  
    "errorFields": { "$map": {
      "input": "$errorFields",
      "as": "ef",
      "in": {  
        "field": "$$ef.field",
        "recordCount": {
            $sum:"$$ef.recordCount"
        },
        "errorDetails": { "$map": {
          "input": "$$ef.errorDetails",
          "as": "ed",
          "in": {
            "detail": "$$ed.detail",
            "recordIds": { "$map": {
              "input": "$$ed.recordIds",
              "as": "ri",
              "in": {
                  $concat: [ "$$ri"]
              }
            }},
            "recordCount": {
                $size:"$$ed.recordIds"
            }
          }
        }}
      }    
    }}
  }}
]).pretty()
```

Here is the mycode method 2:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { groupBy: ObjectId("60f5c60fbc43cb00965ac641") } },
  { $unwind: "$errorFields" },
  { $unwind: "$errorFields.errorDetails" },
  { $unwind: "$errorFields.errorDetails.recordIds" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "_id": "$groupBy",
      "errorFields": {  
        "field": "$errorFields.field",
        "errorDetails": {
          "detail": "$errorFields.errorDetails.detail"
        }
      }
    },
    "recordIds": { 
      "$push" : "$errorFields.errorDetails.recordIds",
    },
    "Idscount": { $sum: 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "errorFields": {
        "field": "$_id.errorFields.field"
      }
    },
    "errorDetails": { 
      "$push": { 
        "recordIds": "$recordIds",
        "detail": "$_id.errorFields.errorDetails.detail",
        "recordCount" : "$Idscount" 
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": 0,
    "errorFields": {    
      "$push": {
        "field": "$_id.errorFields.field",
        "recordCount": "$fieldCount",
        "errorDetails": "$errorDetails"
      }
    }
  }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Please help to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of pasting your whole sample documents which contains a lot of irrelevant fields w.r.t. the question. Please also points out the difference between your expected result and the current result as your expected result is rather big and hard to spot the differece.

Comment: Hi, @ray I have updated the JSON and output formate, could you please check. Can any please help me with this. Thanks